# How to check the values inputted in the JTextField and transfer the string input to an array of characters?

Tags: java, swing

I want to compare every digits of the input number. I am trying to make a DFA program and my DFA accepts strings that does not have any consecutive symbol from 0 and 1.

here's the part of my class that I'm having a trouble with.. I just want to somehow parse and compare each characters/integers...

```
class check implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        JTextField inp= (JTextField) event.getSource();
        char[] text=inp.toCharArray();
        char[] result=new char[text.length];
        int ctr=0;

        while (ctr<result.length)
        {
            if(passy[ctr]==passy[ctr+1])
            {
            }

            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The String is NOT ACCEPTED!");
            }

            ctr++;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having an error in this part:

```
char[] text=inp.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `toCharArray` is undefined for `JTextField`. You need to get the text from the component first. Replace

```
char[] text = inp.toCharArray();
```

with

```
char[] text = inp.getText().toCharArray();
```

Comment: it worked! :) thank you~ very much...do you know how to make an arrow in a JFrame? an arrow object not just lines...

Comment: Have a look at this [BasicArrowButton](http://www.coderanch.com/t/459795/GUI/java/BasicArrowButton-icon), may be useful...